# NTAG212 Mifare Ultralight with Authentication

Tags: java, android, authentication, nfc, mifare

I am new to NFC Android and I have been stuck for days trying to get the Page 4 to page 7 of **NTAG212 Mifare Ultralight with Authentication**, I already have the PWD and PACK to do the **PWD_AUTH** based on the **NTAG212** Docs.

I do this approach...

```
//assume password as array of bytes
//assume pack as array of bytes
try{
nfc.connect();
byte[] cmd1 = nfc.transceive(new byte[]{ (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x00 }); //read the page 0     to make the NFC active
nfc.transceive(new byte[]{
   (byte) 0x1B, //command for PWD_AUTH
   pass[0],
   pass[1],
   pass[2],
   pass[3]
});
byte[] cmd4 = nfc.transceive(new byte[]{ (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x04 }); //read the page 4
}catch(TagLostException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}catch(IOException e){
  e.printStachTrace();
}finally{
    try{
        nfc.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
      //display failed to close
    }
}
```

I always receive a `android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost.` Error after sending the PWD_AUTH command to the NFC. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is my approach correct? Please help.

NOTE: I have read the docs of NTAG212 many times, searched google, stackoverflow and all possible resources.


TIA,
Kenster

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The PWD_AUTH command that you send to the tag does not make much sense.

The idea of the PWD_AUTH command is that you send your password (a 4-byte value) and that the tag responds with its password acknowledge (PACK) value (a 2-byte value) if you authenticated with the correct password. You can then verify the PACK value against the expected password acknowledge to "authenticate" the tag.

So the correct command would be:

```
byte[] response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
    (byte) 0x1B, // PWD_AUTH
    pass[0], pass[1], pass[2], pass[3]
});
if ((response != null) && (response.length >= 2)) {
   byte[] pack = Arrays.copyOf(response, 2);
   // TODO: verify PACK to confirm that tag is authentic (not really,
   // but that whole PWD_AUTH/PACK authentication mechanism was not
   // really meant to bring much security, I hope; same with the
   // NTAG signature btw.)
}
```

What you need in order to enable password protection (on NTAG212):

1. Set PWD (page 39) to your desired password (default value is `0xFFFFFFFF`).

   ```
   byte[] response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
       (byte) 0xA2, // WRITE
       (byte) 39,   // page address
       pass[0], pass[1], pass[2], pass[3]
   });
   ```
2. Set PACK (page 40, bytes 0-1) to your desired password acknowledge (default value is `0x0000`).

   ```
   byte[] response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
       (byte) 0xA2, // WRITE
       (byte) 40,   // page address
       pack[0], pack[1],   // bytes 0-1 are PACK value
       (byte) 0, (byte) 0  // other bytes are RFU and must be written as 0
   });
   ```
3. Set AUTHLIM (page 38, byte 0, bits 2-0) to the maximum number of failed password verification attempts (setting this value to 0 will permit an unlimited number of PWD_AUTH attempts).
4. Set PROT (page 38, byte 0, bit 7) to your desired value (0 = PWD_AUTH in needed only for write access, 1 = PWD_AUTH is necessary for read and write access).

   ```
   byte[] response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
       (byte) 0x30, // READ
       (byte) 38    // page address
   });
   if ((response != null) && (response.length >= 16)) {  // read always returns 4 pages
       boolean prot = false;  // false = PWD_AUTH for write only, true = PWD_AUTH for read and write
       int authlim = 0; // value between 0 and 7
       response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
           (byte) 0xA2, // WRITE
           (byte) 38,   // page address
           (byte) ((response[0] & 0x078) | (prot ? 0x080 : 0x000) | (authlim & 0x007)),
           response[1], response[2], response[3]  // keep old value for bytes 1-3, you could also simply set them to 0 as they are currently RFU and must always be written as 0 (response[1], response[2], response[3] will contain 0 too as they contain the read RFU value)
       });
   }
   ```
5. Set AUTH0 (page 37, byte 3) to the first page that should require password authentication.

   ```
   byte[] response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
       (byte) 0x30, // READ
       (byte) 37    // page address
   });
   if ((response != null) && (response.length >= 16)) {  // read always returns 4 pages
       boolean prot = false;  // false = PWD_AUTH for write only, true = PWD_AUTH for read and write
       int auth0 = 0; // first page to be protected, set to a value between 0 and 37 for NTAG212
       response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
           (byte) 0xA2, // WRITE
           (byte) 37,   // page address
           response[0], // keep old value for byte 0
           response[1], // keep old value for byte 1
           response[2], // keep old value for byte 2
           (byte) (auth0 & 0x0ff)
       });
   }
   ```

If you use `MifareUltralight` tag technology, instead of using the `transceive` method directly, you could also use the `readPages` and `writePage` methods:

- The READ command

  ```
  byte[] response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
      (byte) 0x30,                  // READ
      (byte) (pageAddress & 0x0ff)  // page address
  });
  ```

  is equvalent to

  ```
  byte[] response = nfc.readPages(pageAddress);
  ```
- The WRITE command

  ```
  byte[] data = { (byte)..., (byte)..., (byte)..., (byte)... };
  byte[] response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
      (byte) 0xA2,                  // WRITE
      (byte) (pageAddress & 0x0ff), // page address
      data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]
  });
  ```

  is equvalent to

  ```
  nfc.writePage(pageAddress, data);
  ```

Comment: Hi Michael, I did what you suggest, still getting same error... Is my approach right? I read the page 0 to get the NFC to active state then proceed to PWD_AUTH? or I am missing something. Ty for response btw..

Comment: There is no need to read page 0 before the PWD_AUTH command. The NFC link is activated once you receive the NFC tag dicovery intent and the tag will be activated as soon as you call the connect() method. I assume you are starting the above communication immediately upon receiving the NFC tag dicovery intent, right?

Comment: Some more questions for debugging: **1.** Are you sure that the PWD_AUTH command causes the exception? (I.e. that the exception is not already thrown upon the READ(0) command.) **2.** Are you sure that the password you send to the tag matches the one that is configured in the tag? **3.** Password protection is enabled (i.e. AUTH0 is set to a value lower or equal to the last page address). **4.** If AUTHLIM was set to a value other than 0, you might have used up all authentication attempts (and therefore permanently blocked tag access) with the previous failed authentication attempts.

Comment: 1. Yes after I call the transceive with 0x1B  
2. Yes the password i sent was correct. 
3. This i dont know, It said in docs i have to set it in some bytes but I dont know where to set it. 
4. If the tag is blocked, I cant recover it? 

That AUTH0 thing, in the docs it said that I need to set it to some bytes, also the PROT need to set in some bytes, where can I do that? What page and which bit? It is not said in the docs. Maybe you are right I have used all the attempts, Can you give examples of these? Thanks, It is getting clearer to me now.

Comment: Can we consider a scan of tag without sending PWD_AUTH an attempt to AUTHENTICATE thus making it locked because of too many wrong attempts? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer with regard to the location of password-related configuration settings on NTAG212. **3.** Do read attempts for page 3 (or whatever page you have set password authentication to start at) fail if you didn't perform authentication? **4.** No, read attempts without prior authentication won't count towards AUTHLIM. However, those failed attempts where you sent the PACK bytes together with the PWD bytes in the PWD_AUTH command may (very likely) *have* counted towards failed authentication attempts.

Comment: 1-2. I am not exactly sure how to write the bit7 and bit2. Also the byte3 of AUTH0(what will i set in byte 0-2?). I try to write in page38 with nfc.transceive(new byte[]{ (byte)0xA2, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00 }); but i still have an error with TagLost. can you give example of these?. 3. Yes it fails reading from page3 and up. 4. I see.        I also not mentioned I dont detect NDEF message whenever I scan the tag in NXP Tagreader I get No NFC data set storage in NDEF Tab and the memory size is 32pages with 4 bytes page (but i see 40 pages in docs).

Comment: I am just using NFCa and MifareUltralight transceive commands. Im really lost to this and confuse.

Comment: Typically, you would first read the page, then modify those bits/bytes that you want to change and then write back the whole page (you can only write pages as a whole, so the write command must always contain 4 data bytes). If reading from page 3 onwards fails, you very likely did enable password protection for read and write. In that case it is no wonder that NFC TagInfo (neither the one from NXP nor mine) can read the tag/detect an NDEF message/properly detect the tag size (all of that would require free read access to the whole tag).

Comment: Btw. you can use NfcA or MifareUltralight tag technologies in Android, the transceive method of both tag technologies will do the exact same thing.

Comment: So if thats the case what should i do? I send correct pwd but it fails... the tag is set by the manufacturer before gaving to us. I have new tags that havent scanned yet. But i dont know how to get the data... what seemd.to be the problem in pwd_auth?

Comment: How can i unlocked it? I have the necessary details but dont know what command to send... please can u provide one? Really confuse here... thanks

Comment: So the tags come preprogrammed with a certain password and a certain lock state from your supplier? In that case you can only trust them to have set up password protection correctly. In order to then unlock the password protected tag you would just need to send the PWD_AUTH command. If that fails (i.e. you get the tag lost exception or the transceive method returns a NAK value) the tag is either permanently locked (because of too many failed PWD_AUTH attempts) or the password you sent is wrong. There's not much you can do to further debug the problem in that case.

Comment: So to sum it up? If my PWD i sent was right I can read the PAGE4 - Page7 right? If not its either PWD i sent is wrong or the PWD set by manufacturer is wrong.

Comment: Just one more Michael, Can you give the example code for setting PROT, AUTHLIM, and AUTH0? I just dont understand the 7bit, 2bit and the byte3 for AUTH0. This will be my last request.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information you gave. Ill mark this now as SOLVED since you really solved the problem for PWD_AUTH question. Thanks alot dude. you rock.

Comment: I have a very strange problem, my PWD_AUTH goes through and it returns the pack correctly, but after that my read/writes fail. Strange. Anything else i am missing

Comment: i figured out that if we debug line by line we can get a Transceive error, hence debugging it not recommended when using PWD_AUTH.

Answer (score 0):

One gets the `TagLostException` when sending a wrong password during the `PWD_AUTH` operation.

Make sure the 4-byte password sent in the `PWD_AUTH` operation matches what you used to set the tag's `PWD` field with a regular `WRITE` operation.