# Setting password for NTAG213

Tags: android, authentication, xamarin, nfc, mifare

I am trying to set and check a password in a NFC Tag (type: NTAG213) but I always receive an `IOException` (Transceive failed) when I am trying to set it.

I don't understand which page I have to set for password and ACK pack.
This is my code written in C# with Xamarin. Please feel free to reply in native Android Java code.

```
var tag = intent.GetParcelableExtra (NfcAdapter.ExtraTag) as Tag;

String password = "pass";
byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (password);
MifareUltralight mifare = MifareUltralight.Get (tag);
mifare.Connect ();

byte[] result1 = mifare.Transceive(new byte[] {
        (byte)0xA2,  /* CMD = WRITE */
        (byte)0x2C,  /* PAGE = 44 */
        array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3] 
});

byte[] result2 = mifare.Transceive(new byte[] {
        (byte)0xA2,  /* CMD = WRITE */
        (byte)0x2A,  /* PAGE = 42 */
        (byte)array[0], (byte)array[1], (byte)0, (byte)0 
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With NTAG213, the correct pages for the password (PWD) and the password acknowledge (PACK) are:

- PWD: 43 (`0x2B`)
- PACK: 44 (`0x2C`)

Hence, you are trying to write to the wrong pages. More specifically, you are trying to write non-zero values to RFUI bytes (page 44, bytes 2-3 and page 42, bytes 1-3) which may cause the write operations to fail.

So you would typically want to do something like this:

```
byte[] pwd = new byte[] { (byte)0x70, (byte)0x61, (byte)0x73, (byte)0x73 };
byte[] pack = new byte[] { (byte)0x98, (byte)0x76 };

// write PACK:
byte[] result = mifare.Transceive(new byte[] {
        (byte)0xA2,  /* CMD = WRITE */
        (byte)0x2C,  /* PAGE = 44 */
        pack[0], pack[1], 0, 0
});

// write PWD:
result = mifare.Transceive(new byte[] {
        (byte)0xA2,  /* CMD = WRITE */
        (byte)0x2B,  /* PAGE = 43 */
        pwd[0], pwd[1], pwd[2], pwd[3]
});
```

Note that it does not make much sense to let PACK be a subset of PWD since an attacker would then be able to obtain the PACK value from the PWD value. The PACK value is typically used as a shared secret that only you and the tag "know" and that the tag sends in response to a successful authentication attempt in order to prove that it is a genuine tag. (Though there are quite a lot of security issues with this approach.)

Further note that setting the PWD/PACK values will fail (possibly with an `IOException`) if the tag is already protected (password set and authentication configuration set to protect PWD/PACK). In those cases, you would need to authenticate with the current password first.

Comment: Thank for your quick reply. I did it and the program didn't occur in a exception, but  using NFC Tools app to check nfc status, it let me write on the current tag that should be protected by password. How is it possible?!

Comment: Setting the password is not enough to protect the tag, you have to setup the configuration pages accordingly to actually protect the tag.

Comment: How can I Setting up configuration pages?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22723250/2425802 and consult the data sheet of NTAG213 for the correct page addresses of the configuration values.

Comment: Let's see if I understand everything. I am reading the documenattion of Ntag213, configurations pages are from 41 to 44. 43 is PWD, 44 is PACK, so 41 should be AUTH0 and 42 should be AUTHLIM and PROT. Am I correct?

Comment: I checked and I actually set password and protect Tag from overwriting. Now I have to understand how to remove password.

Comment: I remove password by setting Auth0 to lastpage (0xff), everything was written into documentation, but with your explainations was easier to understand everything!

Comment: Do you know how to check if password protection is enabled or not?

Comment: @lukaspp If the password protection is only enabled for writing, then you can read the configuration pages and check the values to see if password protection is enabled. If the tag is read protected as well, then you can only guess due to the fact that unauthenticated reading beyond AUTH0 fails.

Comment: Ok that's what I did, if I read page 41(Auth0) and the password protection is enabled I get 0000, otherwise I get 000255, but If I read a virgin Nfc Tag I get 0000 as well. Is there another way to check if is password enabled or virgin NFC?

Comment: This actually helped me match the NTAG instruction pages command with how to run it on Android. Now I know how to do everything with NTAG Thanks!

Comment: I added the password on the tag successfully. How can I read the password added when the tag is detected? 

byte[] pack = mifare.readPages((byte) 0x2C);  //Page 44
byte[] password = mifare.readPages((byte) 0x2B); //Page 43

I am checking via not null and array.length > 0 but for all tags I am getting true which is wrong.

Comment: @parthpatibandha reading pwd and pack does not make much sense. The tag will always return these values replaced with zeros. Hence, the readPages command is successful and the returned array should contain 4 bytes (=1 page). If you want to verify the password and (as a result of successful verification) get the pack value, you need to use the PWD_AUTH command. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44395283/2425802