# Write password protected NFC tag in Flutter or Android

Tags: android, flutter, nfc

I am developing a NFC app in Flutter but due to unavailability of Plugin which provides **write password protected NFC tag**.
So, i decided to write platform specific code for Android & iOS.

There are many plugin available for read & write NFC tag but not password protected.

If anyone has idea how to implement write password protected NFC tag in **Flutter** or **Android** then please share with me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What type (make and model) of the tag?, as different types of tag have different password protection mechanisms.

Comment: Its a NFC NTAG 216

Comment: NTAG 216 is a Mifare ultralight type tag, details of setting and using password for this type of tag can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44546511/2373819 for Android, for iOS you send the same commands to the tag. This all comes from the datasheet for the tag at https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf

Comment: I should have also pointed out that the 213 and 215 and 216 exact commands are slightly different because the config pages are at the end of the card and due to the different sizes you have to adjust the page address to each size of card (all in the datasheet)

Comment: Hi @SandipPatel are you able to lock and unlock the nfc tag. I have the same requirement in one application