# Read NDEF message with external NFC reader ACR1252

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, apdu, ndef

I am using the following command to read a binary block from a Mifare Ultralight tag: `FF B0 00 01 04`

But now I want to exact the NDEF message stored in that Mifare Ultralight tag using an ACR1252 NFC reader. Which command do I have to use to get the full NDEF message? On which position in the tag is the NDEF message stored?

Answer (score 3):

MIFARE Ultralight tags map to the <strike>[NFC Forum Type 2 Tag Operation specification](http://www.cardsys.dk/download/NFC_Docs/NFC%20Forum%20Type%202%20Tag%20Operation%20Specification%201.1.pdf)</strike> (broken link, [here is an alternative](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf). Consequently, in order to extract the NDEF message from such a tag, you would need to follow the read procedure defined by that specification.

You already found the read command for your reader:

```
FF B0 00 BLOCK_NUMBER 10
```

With that command (note the value 0x10 for the length field) you read 4 consecutive blocks starting at `BLOCK_NUMBER`.

You would then first read the capability container (located at block 3):

```
FF B0 00 03 10
```

The first 4 bytes (1 block) are the capability container:

- Byte 0 is set to the "magic" value `0xE1` to indicate that the tag uses an NDEF mapping following the NFC Forum Type 2 Tag Operation specification.
- Byte 1 indicates the mapping version.
- Byte 2 indicates the memory size of the tag.
- Byte 3 indicates access restrictions.

Once you verified that the tag matches the NDEF mapping specification, you can read data starting at block 4 (you already read blocks 4-6 with the above command). Those blocks contain the NDEF message in a TLV structure with the tag 0x03. See [Writing NDEF data to NTAG216 tag using low-level NFC communication methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42105626/2425802) for details on TLV structures.